# I want to add array elements together but it just slaps them to one another

Tags: javascript

I want to add "K" number of elements from an array together. However every time i run the program it just slaps each value from the array to one another.

```
    let N=prompt("write number of elements N");
    let K=prompt("write number of elements K");

    var arr= [];
    for(let i=0; i<N ; i++){
      arr[i]=prompt("write each number");
    }
    arr.sort();
    arr.reverse();
  //problematic code:  
    var sum= 0;
    for (let i=0 ; i<K; i++){
      sum+= arr[i];
    }
    console.log(sum);
```

-The whole problem is to find the biggest possible sum from an array with N elements using K element from the user input.
I don't get the sum at the end just each value slapped together.
-The expected output is 7+8+9=24. However it just slaps them together: 7+8+9=789

Comment: Because `prompt("write each number");` returns a string, you have to typecast it to a number before proceeding, do `Number(prompt("write each number");)`

Answer (score 1):

It is because prompt return a string and not an number.Simply convert it to number before adding them to array:

```js
let N=prompt("write number of elements N");
let K=prompt("write number of elements K");

var arr= [];
for(let i=0; i<N ; i++){
  arr[i]=Number(prompt("write each number"));
}
arr.sort();
arr.reverse();

var sum= 0;
for (let i=0 ; i<K; i++){
  sum+= arr[i];
}
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Some documentation: https://gomakethings.com/converting-strings-to-numbers-with-vanilla-javascript/

Comment: You need to parse your N, K as integers. They are strings

Comment: Best way to convert string to number is Unary Plus `+`.